# Reconnecting to Battle.net while in-game?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battle.net

Immediately after I enter the world on a slower computer, I am sometimes disconnected from Battle.net. The game functions properly, except RealID is disabled. To regain RealID, one solution is to relog, but this does not always solve the issue (and it's undesirable when logging in takes a few minutes).

Is there any way to reconnect to Battle.net while in-game without relogging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the /reload input will sometimes basically "refresh" your game. Which may include reconnecting you to battle.net. Mainly used for Ui resetting but I have found that it does re-log your chat. So it would be worth a shot in your situation.

Comment: Thanks, stay. Since the last patch, I haven't been able to reproduce the issue--maybe they've resolved it on their end? If it happens again, I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue... If this error appears frequently try to solve it by deleting the folders `Cache`, `Cache` in the `Data` folder, `Interface` and `WTF`.